# Finding if substrings of key phrase exist in sentence or not

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if key exists in given sentence or not.

But in the sentence, the key can be jumbled, or there can be special characters in between, or the key can have some words between them.
Right now I'm not worried about case sensitive.

For example, I want to check if:

- "Motor101" key exists in statement "Device Motor_101 is very high" or
- "Motor101" key exists in statement "101Motor Device is very high" or
- "Motor101" key exists in statement "Motor device 101 is very is high"

I started with comparing character-by-character from key to statement, but I was not able to solve the problem.

Based on comments, I tired to come up with code.

```
def getMatch(text,key):
matchedwords=list()
i=0
for j in range(0, len(text)):
    for i in range(0,len(key)):
        match = ""
        keyindex=i
        textindex=j
        while(keyindex<len(key) and textindex<len(text) and key[keyindex]==text[textindex] ):
            match+=text[textindex]
            keyindex+=1
            textindex+=1
        if(len(match)>0):
            if(match not in matchedwords):
                matchedwords.append(match)
print(matchedwords)

text="MOTOR Device 101 is high"
key="MOTOR101"
getMatch(text,key)
```

I was able to get the output as"['MOTOR', 'OTOR', 'O', 'TOR', 'OR', 'R', '101', '1', '01']".
Please let me know if any changes is required or improvement can be done.
From here I'm here trying to check if any combination of words leads to "MOTOR101".

Comment: How jumbled can the key be? For example, would the statement "Motice Devor 110" be accepted? Or should "Motor" and "101" maintain full integrity?

Comment: Yes this statement would be accepted "Motor device 101", here is challenge what I'm facing how can I find if motor101 exists in "Motor device 101" or some other scenarios which I mentioned in above question

Comment: We could write a regex with a lookahead assertion for each substring: `r'(?=.*Motor)(?=.*101)'`. How many intervening characters and what type do you allow (symbols only? alphanumerics?) Do we match 'Motorr...2101234'?

Comment: This is a tricky problem.  I ASSUME you are not literally looking for "Motor101", but that you actually have a set of keywords.  If I were doing this, I think I'd search for the keyword ("motor"), then search for the item numbers, and if I found a keyword within a certain number of characters of an item number, then that was probably a match.

Comment: I have a solution but it requires you to split your search string into components. As many components as you link. `['Motor', '101']`

Comment: This is an interesting question, but not clearly stated. pasupati, we need you to give clarifications to the different things people have asked you. There are countless ways to define a match or non-match.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for two separate items in string. If you split them into a list then the following code will find them.

```py
lk = [ 'Motor','101' ]
s1 = [ 'Device Motor_101 is very high',
       '101Motor Device is very high',
       'Motor device 101 is very is high' ]

for i, a in enumerate( s1 ):
    result = -1
    for b in a.split():
        if lk[0] in b:
            result = i
        if lk[1] in b:
            if result > -1:
                print( f'found in {a}' )
```

This code will search and find more than just two items

```py
lk = [ 'Motor','101' ]
ln = len( lk )
s1 = [ 'Device Motor_101 is very high',
       '101Motor Device is very high',
       'Motor device 101 is very is high' ]

found = []
for i, a in enumerate( s1 ):
    for b in a.split():
        result = -1
        for gp in range( ln ):
            if lk[ gp ] in b:
                result += 1
        if result > -1 and found.count( a ) == 0:
            found.append( a )
            print( f'found in {a}' )
print( f'{found}' )
```

Ok I've found that duplications of words cause false positives so...
Here is my third attempt

```py
lk = [ 'sky', '101', 'Motor', 'very' ]
ln = len( lk )
s1 = [ 'Device Motor_101 is very high in sky',
       '101Motor Device is sky sky very',
       'Motor device is very is high very very' ]

found = []
for i, a in enumerate( s1 ):
    result = 0
    sa = a.split( )
    for b in a.split():
        for gp in range( ln ):
            if lk[ gp ] in b:
                if b in sa:
                    sa.remove( b )
                    result += 1
    if result == ln-1:
        found.append( a )

print( f'{found}' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but here key would be MOTOR101. Can we find if any of the subset from s1 contains our key or not. I came up with some code where I updated the in my question. Can you please let me know if there can be any improvement in that.

Comment: I have a solution @pasupati My original code was based upon a presumption of just two items to look for. This code has one such presumption.

Comment: Oops! forgot to accumulate the result. Now it works correctly.

Comment: This is trickier than I thought but it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for `Motor` and `101` individually and then return the status if both are present or not.

```
def get_match(s):
    lookup = ['Motor', '101']
    count = 0
    for i in lookup:
        if i in s:
            count += 1
        if count == len(lookup):
            return 'Strings Present'
    return 'Not Present'

    

print(get_match('Device Motor_101 is very high'))
print(get_match('Stackoverflow 101'))
print(get_match('101Motor Device is very high'))
print(get_match('Motor device 101 is very is high'))
print(get_match('Motorbikes are good'))
```

```
Output:

Strings Present
Not Present
Strings Present
Strings Present
Not Present
```